# Any Lua pattern alternative to the regex (\\.|.)?

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

There's a common idiom for traversing a string whose characters may be escaped with a backslash by using the regex `(\\.|.)`, like this:

```
alert( "some\\astring".replace(/(\\.|.)/g, "[$1]") )
```

That's in JavaScript. This code changes the string `some\astring` to `[s][o][m][e][\a][s][t][r][i][n][g]`.

I know that Lua patterns don't support the OR operator, so we can't translate this regular expression directly into a Lua pattern.

Yet, I was wondering: is there an alternative way to do this (traversing possibly-escaped characters) in Lua, using a Lua pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
(\\?.)
```

and replace with `[$1]`

See [it on Regexr](http://regexr.com/v1?38l1r).

`?` is a shortcut quantifier for 0 or 1 occurences, so the above pattern is matching a character and an optional backslash before. If `?` is not working (I don't know lua) you can try `{0,1}` instead. That is the long version of the same.

Comment: Nice answer. To make it clearer in case the OP is wondering, in `(\\.|.)` the order of the alternation is important, but since `?` is a greedy quantifier it will indeed always try `\\.` before trying `.` (`{0,1}` will try the `1` solution first too)

Comment: In Lua, `%1` is in the place of `$1`. Other than that, your pattern should work: `string.gsub("some\\astring", "(\\?.)", "[%1]")`

Comment: Wow, thanks for the simple answer! (I hope I'm not the only one who sometimes fail to see the simple solutions...)